# Getting a total sum in a nested object

Tags: python, loops, sum, iterable

```
with jsonlines.open('myfile.jsonl') as readfile:
    for contents in readfile:
        print (len(contents['tokens']))
```

So, I have a jsonl file where each line is a dictionary that contains lists, dictionaries, strings and integers. I want to loop through the len() of a list on every line and get a total overall length. So the code here gives me:
*4
11
7
12
9
7
14
9
10
10
4
8*

But I want to a total, abd when I try to sum() or count() or anything I get a

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Each jsonl line looks something like this, so you can see it's very nested. I want to count the len() of each "tokens" key on each line and add them all together.

*{“text”:”full text...”,”","_input_hash":-random number,"_task_hash":-random number,"tokens":[{"text":"word","start":number,"end":number,"id":number,"ws":true or false},{"text":"word","start":number,"end":number,"id"number,"ws":true or false}...],"_session_id":"dataset name-annotator name","_view_id":"ner_manual","spans":[{"start":number,"end":number,"token_start":number,"token_end":number,"label":"POS tag"},"answer":"accept"}*

Comment: please show your code which throws the error and a relevant snippet of the input json

Answer (score 0):

You can simply accumulate the lengthes:

```
with jsonlines.open('myfile.jsonl') as readfile:
    total = 0
    for contents in readfile:
        total += len(contents['tokens'])
    print(total)
```

Or use `sum` on an appropriate generator expression:

```
with jsonlines.open('myfile.jsonl') as readfile:
    total = sum(len(contents['tokens']) for contents in readfile)
    print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic solution would be to use a generator expression i.e. a for loop that can be consumed by a function:

```py
with jsonlines.open('myfile.jsonl') as readfile:
    total_tokens = sum(len(contents['tokens']) for contents in readfile)
    print(total_tokens)
```